# Is Indy 9 compatible with Lazarus/Free Pascal

Tags: delphi, indy, freepascal, indy-9

I'm doing feasibility analysis about porting a delphi 7 app to Free Pascal. Does Indy 9 work on Free Pascal? Do you need a special build or just the latest Indy 9 from Indy's svn repository? Or would I have to upgrade to Indy 10 to get the app working in Free Pascal at all? It appears quite clear that Indy 10 would work, but the answer for Indy 9 appears a bit more murky, and I can't find anything remotely recent on the matter.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason you can't use Indy 10?  The only cases I found that took any work at all, were if you had custom components that relied on things that had to be modified/rewritten for indy 10. Even then, such a change was not too hard, I have done it (grumble grumble mutter) and it was not that hard.

Comment: Before I started working on the project, an attempt to port to indy 10 had been made and it did have some showstopping bug that caused that branch to be abandoned. But that's not to say that if I poked at it long enough I couldn't potentially fix it and upgrade it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2005, I patched Indy 9 to work with FPC. It is **only** for **Windows 32-bit** though, and afterwards I migrated to Indy 10, so the result was not maintained.

I searched a bit and the main port seems to be http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/indy/indy9forfpc.zip

A few months later I added this archive  http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/indy/indy9.zip which I suspect is my general indy9 working dir, and may contain some demoes not in the former archive.

I hope the **not maintained since 2005** says enough. IOW, use Indy 10.

Answer (score 3):

Indy 9 does not officially support FPC.  On the other hand, I don't know if anyone has ever tried getting it to work with FPC, either.  You could try creating a FPC project, add the source files to it, and see what happens.